# How can I Send DM to certain user with ID?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```
let user = client.users.cache.get(config.admin);
...
user.send(exampleEmbed);
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined

```
    "admin": "451744624......"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whats going on here, is that your admin isn't cached. 
So it doesn't exist in `client.users.cache.get(<id>)`.

However you CAN cache it by instead using: `client.users.fetch(<id>)`
Which I recommend, as not only does it cache the user, but it returns the user's cache if it's already cached.

Answer (score 0):

The user cannot be found, the user must be in a server that the bot is in; in order to be able to directly message them.